# Does Azure blockBlobURL.download() have a limit to file size?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage, nodejs-stream

I'm using Azure's `blockBlobURL.download()` to download an image but am only receiving the top portion of the image. Is there a limit to how much I can download from Azure blob to a readable stream? The content length is 172628 and there exists a property `highWaterMark: 16384`. Are these to related?

```
async function compareToBaseline(imageData, blobName, metadata){

  const baselineBlobName = "MacOSX10.12/chrome/initial"

  const containerURL = ContainerURL.fromServiceURL(serviceURL, "baselines")
  const blockBlobURL = BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, baselineBlobName );
  let baseLineImage = await blockBlobURL.download(aborter, 0)

  baseLineImage = baseLineImage.originalResponse.readableStreamBody.read()
  console.log(baseLineImage.length);

  baseLineImage = new Buffer(baseLineImage, 'base64');
  await fs.writeFile('./newest.png', baseLineImage, 'binary', function(err){
    console.log('written');
  })
}
```

The result is only the top portion of an image.

Comment: I can't write a proper answer right now, but `read()` only returns a chunk of data, you need to loop until it returns `null`, see [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size)

Comment: Would I be able to loop over that data and keeping appending the data to a variable and eventually write that data to the filesystem? Or would I need to pipe it continuously to the filesystem? If I understand correctly.

Comment: Ideally you'd pipe it to the file system instead of first putting the data in a variable, in order to limit memory consumption. In this case probably you won't even need to call `read()` in a loop, I assume `fs` supports writing a stream straight to a file.

Comment: `read()` returns `null` doesn't mean there is no more data in the stream. You need to follow Node.js practices to get all data by listening to `data` or `readable` event. For example, `readable.on('readable', () => {
  let chunk;
  while (null !== (chunk = readable.read())) {
    console.log(`Received ${chunk.length} bytes of data.`);
  }
});`

Answer (score 1):

There's a 4-MB limit for each call to the Azure Storage service. If your file is larger than 4 MB, you must break it in chunks. For more information, see [Azure Storage scalability and performance targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-scalability-targets).

Here is sample c# code to download very large files in 1MB chunks. it's performance oriented too.

```
 private static void DownloadLargeFile()
        {
            string connectionString = "connString"; //ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"]; //blob connection string
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
#pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
            string sourceContainerName = "quickstartblob"; //ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["sourcecontainerName"]; //source blob container name            
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
            string sourceBlobFileName = "QuickStart1.txt"; //source blob name
            CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(sourceContainerName);
            var file = sourceBlobFileName;
            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(file);
            //First fetch the size of the blob. We use this to create an empty file with size = blob's size
            blob.FetchAttributes();
            var blobSize = blob.Properties.Length;
            long blockSize = (1 * 1024 * 1024);//1 MB chunk;
            blockSize = Math.Min(blobSize, blockSize);
            //Create an empty file of blob size
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))//Create empty file.
            {
                fs.SetLength(blobSize);//Set its size
            }
            var blobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions
            {
                RetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 3),
                MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
                ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)
            };
            long currentPointer = 0;
            long bytesRemaining = blobSize;
            do
            {
                var bytesToFetch = Math.Min(blockSize, bytesRemaining);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    //Download range (by default 1 MB)
                    blob.DownloadRangeToStream(ms, currentPointer, bytesToFetch, null, blobRequestOptions);
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    var contents = ms.ToArray();
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))//Open that file
                    {
                        fs.Position = currentPointer;//Move the cursor to the end of file.
                        fs.Write(contents, 0, contents.Length);//Write the contents to the end of file.
                    }
                    currentPointer += contents.Length;//Update pointer
                    bytesRemaining -= contents.Length;//Update bytes to fetch
                }
            }
            while (bytesRemaining > 0);
        }
```

Something like below in node js

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function (context, input) {

context.done();

var accessKey = 'myaccesskey';
var storageAccount = 'mystorageaccount';
var containerName = 'mycontainer';

var blobService = azure.createBlobService(storageAccount, accessKey);

var recordName = "a_large_movie.mov";
var blobName = "standard/mov/" + recordName;

var blobSize;
var chunkSize = (1024 * 512) * 8; // I'm experimenting with this variable
var startPos = 0;
var fullPath = "D:/home/site/wwwroot/myAzureFunction/input/";
var blobProperties = blobService.getBlobProperties(containerName, blobName,   null, function (error, blob) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    else    {
        blobSize = blob.contentLength;
        context.log('Registered length: ' + blobSize);
        fullPath = fullPath + recordName;
        console.log(fullPath);
        doDownload();
    }
}
);

function doDownload() {
var stream = fs.createWriteStream(fullPath, {flags: 'a'});
var endPos = startPos + chunkSize;
if (endPos > blobSize) {
    endPos = blobSize;
    context.log('Reached end of file endPos: ' + endPos);
}

context.log("Downloading " + (endPos - startPos) + " bytes starting from " + startPos + " marker.");

blobService.getBlobToStream(
    containerName, 
    blobName, 
    stream, 
    { 
        "rangeStart": startPos, 
        "rangeEnd": endPos-1 
    }, 
    function(error) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        else if (!error) {
            startPos = endPos;
            if (startPos <= blobSize - 1) {
                doDownload();
            }
        }
    }
);
}

};
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

blockBlobURL.download() doesn't have a limit to file size. But `read()` returns null doesn't mean no more data in the stream. You need to follow Node.js practices to get all data by listening to `data` or `readable` event.

For example, the `data` event posted by Peter Pan. Or the `readable` event posted by Node.js official documents:

```
readable.on('readable', () => {
  let chunk;
  while (null !== (chunk = readable.read())) {
    console.log(`Received ${chunk.length} bytes of data.`);
  }
});
```

**Please always call `read()` inside `readable` event callback.**

Answer (score -1):

It seems that this issue was similar with your other thread [Unable to read readableStreamBody from downloaded blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56465924/unable-to-read-readablestreambody-from-downloaded-blob/56475452#56475452).

Here is my function to help saving the `baseLineImage.readableStreamBody` to a file, as below.

```
async function streamToFs(filename, readableStream) {
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
    readableStream.on("data", data => {
      ws.write(data);
    }).on("end", () => {
      console.log('written');
    });
}
```

And change your code as below.

```
async function compareToBaseline(imageData, blobName, metadata){

  const baselineBlobName = "MacOSX10.12/chrome/initial"

  const containerURL = ContainerURL.fromServiceURL(serviceURL, "baselines");
  const blockBlobURL = BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, baselineBlobName );
  let baseLineImage = await blockBlobURL.download(aborter, 0);

  await streamToFs('./newest.png', baseLineImage.readableStreamBody)；
}
```

It works. Hope it helps.